# Remove text after a dot and a colon in Woocommerce product title

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic, title

In my product title, I would like to remove all the text content after the first dot "." or colon ":".

For instance I would like to transform :
 Theodore Deck : The Peter Marino Collection => Theodore Deck

I tried this code from [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24335239/wordpress-remove-everything-after-a-specific-character)but without success.

```
function explode_parts($title, $id){
    $parts = explode(' : ', $title);
    $before = $parts[0]; //before the :
    $after = $parts[1]; //after the : 
    return (whatever);
}

add_filter('the_title', 'explode_parts');
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using following code:

```
add_filter('the_title', 'mod_product__title', 10, 2);
function mod_product__title($title, $id) {

    if( is_product() ) {
        if(preg_match('/[^(:|.)]*/', $title, $matches)){
            return trim($matches[0]);
        }else{
            return $title;
        }
    }
    return $title;
}
```

Here I'm using regex to match `.` or `:` . Regex will match only the first occurrence and return the text before it. Then I'm using `trim()` to get rid of any extra trailing space. If it doesn't match anything then it will return the full title.

### UPDATE

Following code checks up wheather it's admin list or front-end and modifies title accordingly

```
add_filter('the_title', 'mod_product__title', 10, 2);
function mod_product__title($title, $id) {
    global $pagenow;
    if ( $pagenow != 'edit.php' && get_post_type( $id ) == 'product' ) {
        if(preg_match('/[^(:|.)]*/', $title, $matches)){
            return trim($matches[0]);
        }else{
            return $title;
        }
    }
    return $title;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've put this code in my function.php file but it seems not working. I still see text after : or . in the product title.

Any idea why?

Comment: I've modified the answer. check please.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot!